# Comparing by section two numpy arrays in python

Tags: python, arrays, python-2.7, numpy

I want to do a comparison between the two arrays by section.
so far I have to get results for all arrays.

```
import numpy as np
array1 = np.array(list(np.zeros(20))+(list(np.ones(20)))+(list(2*np.ones(20))))
array2 = np.array(list(np.ones(20))+(list(np.ones(20)))+(list(3*np.ones(20))))
result = np.sum(array1 == array2)
print 'all result :' + str(result)
```

how to can result in parts, such as the first data 20 then 20 the second data and 20 third data in the array??
the result should be:

all result : 20

result for 20 firt data : 0

result for 20 second data : 20

result for 20 third data : 0

Comment: `np.array(list(np.zeros(20))+(list(np.ones(20)))+(list(2*np.ones(20))))` is better spelt `np.concatenate([np.zeros(20), np.ones(20), 2*np.ones(20)])`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First off, let's get the mask of comparisons -

```
mask = array1 == array2
```

Then, to get all sum -

```
allsum = mask.sum()
```

And to get sectionwise (of length `20`) sum -

```
section_sums = mask.reshape(-1,20).sum(1)
```

Sample run -

```
In [77]: mask = array1 == array2

In [78]: mask.sum()
Out[78]: 20

In [79]: mask.reshape(-1,20).sum(1)
Out[79]: array([ 0, 20,  0])
```

---

**For generic lengths**

If the length of input arrays are not guaranteed to be a multiple of `20`, we could use an approach using `np.bincount` to get `section_sums`, like so -

```
section_sums = np.bincount(np.arange(mask.size)//20,mask)
```

Sample run -

```
In [5]: a1=np.array(list(np.zeros(20))+(list(np.ones(20)))+(list(2*np.ones(17))))
   ...: a2=np.array(list(np.ones(20))+(list(np.ones(20)))+(list(3*np.ones(17))))
   ...: 

In [6]: mask = a1==a2

In [7]: np.bincount(np.arange(mask.size)//20,mask)
Out[7]: array([  0.,  20.,   0.])
```

Comment: @OP: Note this fails if your arrays is of a length that is not a multiple of 20

Comment: Style point: the docs seem to favor passing `axis` as a kwarg: `.sum(axis=1)`

Comment: @RiskaNanda That means `sum` along the second axis of the 2D reshaped array. Shorthand notation for the same becomes `.sum(1)` as we skip stating the `axis` parameter.

Answer (score 1):

Just sum each 20 separately:

```
matches = array1 == array2
print 'first  20: {}'.format(matches[:20].sum())
print 'second 20: {}'.format(matches[20:40].sum())
print 'third  20: {}'.format(matches[40:60].sum())
```

`np.sum(x)` is usually equivalent to `x.sum()`